# How do I connect to a ServerSocket that is outside my local wifi?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have been looking around on the internet for about an hour now and I can't seem to find an answer to my question.
I would like to know the best way to connect to a ServerSocket that is running on a computer which is not on the same wifi as the client. I have previously worked with clients and servers, but only when both the client(s) and the server were on the same wifi.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Same way as anywhere. With an IP address and an open port.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your quick reply. But doesn't that only work if you are on the same network? What I am trying to achieve is having a server at my house and then being able to connect to it from somewhere else (kilometers away)

Comment: You are on the same network. The internet.

Comment: @Kayaman so I would be able to connect to server just by creating a socket like this: new Socket(String IPv4 address, String port) ?

Comment: If it's listening on that port and not blocked by a firewall. If it's a home computer, then you need to set port forwarding from the router to the actual end point.

Comment: @Kayaman alright, thank you very much. Will I need to set up the port forwarding aspect even if a disable the firewall and listen on the correct port?

Comment: Yes, because the outside IP address is that of the router doing NAT. You'll need to configure it to redirect connections to given ports to the internal IP of your computer.

Comment: @Kayaman alright I'll look into that! Thank you very much, I appreciate it